# How to work as a freelancer using SharePoint on-premise

Tags: remote, programmer

I want to pursue a career as a freelancer. I have an experience using SharePoint (on-premise). For those who are not familiar with the on-premise, it means that when I will deploy my solution/work, I will be deploying the solution (.wsp) to the server.

In the freelancing world, how will this work? will I just send the .wsp to the client? should I also include the source code, even documentations etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the fabulous/evil world of Freelancing, being your own boss*.

`* Kinda.... Not really`

First off, do you have a portfolio? If not, create one, ASAP. Your clients need to see what you're capable of. If you did work for companies already, ask their permission to show case your work from their sites.

Next, you need to think like the person who'd be hiring you - what would you want? If you are starting a new company that sells XYZ Widgets, and you want a Sharepoint site, what are you looking to get out of the deal? Probably not just a nice looking JPEG image, you want the whole site! I don't know Sharepoint very well, but I know if I hired you, I'd want all the files you worked on that we need - source code extra if it's a compiled program. Include documentation whenever possible, or else you'll get inundated with phone calls asking how to do simple things.

Next, what does your contract say? If you don't have contracts, be aware that you are opening yourself up to horrible things - Scope creep, getting sued, getting ripped off, lost time, stress, cranky customers, and more. Get a contract and a Scope of Work made up that clearly defines every term. There are many questions on this site about what should be included in both.

Comment: If the companies you work for won't open up their intranets to the outside world, you should at least be able to display static screencaps of non-proprietary pages. (I did some UI design for a SharePoint Intranet that people outside the company can't access, but I'm allowed to show my home page design as a screencap in my portfolio)